# How do I compensate for lack of exposure lock on a Canon AV-1?

Tags: canon, exposure, film, 35mm

I just got my first roll of film printed and noticed that some of the exposures were off. I don't know why I didn't notice this before but there isn't an AE-lock on the [Canon AV-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_AV-1).

My question is, does anyone have any suggestions to compensate for the lack of exposure lock? Most of my subjects aren't centered and I need to be able to compensate quickly without losing the moment nor the mood of the picture...

Comment: NB: this camera also lacks a fully-manual mode.

Comment: yup, only shoots in aperture priority mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had this issue and this is what I did. Take your desired exposure on your subject. Lets say you need a shutter speed of 1/50. Then, move you camera to where you want to place the shot, and adjust the ISO dial.

So, if you want you shutter slower, take your ISO down, else take it up. This works perfectly for me, not the quickest, but then again, this camera is old! still a nice camera.

Makes sense ?

Comment: so pretty much adjust the ASA dial to get the same shutter speed... I was somewhat afraid of that, it's a 2 handed operation meaning I'll have to look at the dial and then back to the viewfinder and since I do street photography from time to time I'll most likely miss the moment...

Comment: Yip, but its not that time consuming. But if you need the speed, this is not the camera.

Comment: yeah, I guess I'll try to find an AE-1 Program instead.. Upvoted your answer and if nothing else comes up I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: shotto robotto! good luck